# Galaxy S3 Ice Cream emulator doesn't start on Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, galaxy

I created a new emulator device & AVD on my Android development environment. I had one working for the Galaxy Ace 2. I created a new device & virtual machine for the Samsung Galaxy S3 (Icre Cream) but it doesn't work.

It first shows the emulator window with a plain text ANDROID on the upper left or so. After a while it changes to the next phase (same as in the other emulator) which displays the word ANDROID with funky letter type and an animation on the letters. But it never gets past that.

On the working emulator it goes to the next phase which displays the Android screen unblocking , which after unblocking loads the app being tested.

So why is the S3 emulation NOT starting? My S3 is targetted at Android API Level 15 and in the Android SDK Manager I have the following in the Android API 15 (4.0.3):

- SDK Platform (installed)
- ARMEABI v7a System Image (installed)

If I try the Nexus 7 emulator that was already installed by default, it does not even show the emulator screen, it only says "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information." and that's it.

So basically the only emulator that works is the Ace 2 I created.

Comment: How long have you left the S3 emulator to start? It takes 20-25 minutes for an Android v4 emulator to start up for the first time on my machine. After that with a snapshot, it still takes several minutes. Oh, and yes, my dev machine is an old one. Even on newer higher spc machines, the later API emulators can take quite some time to start.

Comment: Hum... I left it for about 10 minutes, after that it seemed pretty hopeless to wait for more on a fast machine. Will try longer.

Comment: A good tip is to keep RAM / SD card sizes to the absolute minimum you need as these are allocated directly from your PC's real RAM. I have a Nexus 4 emulator, for example, which only has 128MB internal RAM and 32MB SD card emulation as that's all I need for testing.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks, your last comment did it. I originally had it with the actual memory specs, way too much for emulation as I realize. With that I could leave it for a couple of hours and it wouldn't go past "Android".. I changed the memory (RAM & SD Card) to what you use, i.e. 128MB/32MB) and now in about 2 minutes I have the S3 emulator running. I don't know if this also helped but I installed a few other SDK packages as well.